# Bitwise operators - differences between C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, bit-manipulation

I'm working on porting a C++ project to Java and I've become stuck on a bitwise operation that seems very simple but I'm getting different results in C++ than in Java. Consider the following.

```
long xor = 2654435769L;
xor ^= xor << 0x0B;
```

In C++ the (correct) value is 637186489 but in Java it's 5433770815929.

What am I missing here?

Comment: long in java is 64 bits, long in c++ depends  on your compiler but is typically 32 bits.  the expression in c++ silently dropped bits as they were shifted 11 bits to the left, but java didn't.

Comment: Who says the C++ value is "correct"? Print us up `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: As @davidbak said, the Java answer is correct, not the C++ one.  2654435769 << 11 is 5436284454912.  2654435769 ^ 5436284454912 is 5433770815929 - see http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/ to prove it to yourself.

Comment: Java has same "correct" answer as C++ if you change `xor` to `int` in Java. Proof that @davidbak is right. Of course `2654435769` is not actually a valid signed 32-bit value, but that's a different issue, where the C++ code is "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

The `long` datatype in java is 64 bits.  Try using `int` instead.  Basically, wherever you have a `long` or `int` in C++, use ONLY `int` in Java.  If you have a `long long` in C++, THEN you use `long` in Java.

Edit:  Your title is a bit vague.  You should reword it so that people know you're trying to convert C++ code to Java.